# Could not find OpenSSL If it's already installed, please set the OPENSSL_PREFIX environment variable accordingly

Tags: perl, openssl, debian, cpan

When I try to install [`Net::SSLeay`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay) on Debian, I'm getting

```
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at Makefile.PL line 290.
Use of uninitialized value $exec in -x at Makefile.PL line 108.
*** Could not find OpenSSL
    If it's already installed, please set the OPENSSL_PREFIX environment
    variable accordingly. If it isn't installed yet, get the latest version
    from http://www.openssl.org/.
N/A
```

But I do have OpenSSL installed,

```
$ dpkg -l libssl-dev
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name             Version      Architecture Description
+++-================-============-============-================================================
ii  libssl-dev:amd64 1.1.1b-2     amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
```

I've tried playing with `OPENSSL_PREFIX` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **not** an error that results from being unable to locate headers (provided by `-dev`), but because it can't find the openssl binary utility. The headers are still required, but you need the binary `openssl` utility too. You can either install the `Net::SSLeay` with apt itself, or build the module from source. The simple method, installing `Net::SSLeay` from apt, can be done with

```
sudo apt install libnet-ssleay-perl
```

Alternatively you can install the binary `openssl`, and try to install again with cpan.

```
sudo apt install openssl libssl-dev zlib1g-dev ## all requirements to build Net::SSLeay
cpanm Net::SSLeay
```

You can verify `openssl` is installed with (if this works, the error above should not be reproducible)

```
openssl version
```

Comment: so, the env variable `OPENSSL_PREFIX` is not a good test? This variable is not for production.